# undefined method `authenticate' for ...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

undefined method `authenticate' for #<User id: 2, email: "user@user.com", cne: "1234", password: [FILTERED], created_at: "2021-04-01 04:13:39.722980000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-04-01 04:13:39.722980000 +0000">

**code**

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email:login_params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(login_params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/dashboard'
    else
      flash[:login_params]=['login faild!,retry']
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end
```

Comment: have you added 'bcrypt' gem in your gem file and bundle it ?

Comment: yeah i did and i updated it

Comment: has_secure_password => add this in your model

Answer (score 0):

```
  gem 'bcrypt'
```

Add the above gem in your gem file and bundle it

```
  has_secure_password
```

Add the above line of code in you user model i.e., user.rb